# Adding label or supporting text to a loading animation (spinner)

Tags: usability, progress-bar, loading, spinner

I have an interactive map container that requires some time to load. I placed an animated loading spinner while the map loads.

Is the animated spinner sufficient visual feedback or should it be accompanied by text?

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays a spinning circle is a good enough indicator of loading.

However it might be a good idea to preload some data for the map, rather than leaving it an empty rectangle. This way people can also see *what* is loading.

Answer (score 2):

If it is close to 10secs or above then yes an indication of what is being loaded and how much is the progress should be added ([source](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/))

> Anything slower than 10 seconds needs a percent-done indicator as well as a clearly signposted way for the user to interrupt the operation.